# I want to get source ip address from webclient instance.

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, network-programming

I want to know source ip actually used, so I want to get source ip address from web instance. 
How can I find the source ip actual used?
I want to check from visual studio without using network analyzer(e.g. wireshark)

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<WebClientEx> li = new List<WebClientEx>();
            li.Add(new WebClientEx() { ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("Source IP Address 1"), 0) });
            li.Add(new WebClientEx() { ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("Source IP Address 2"), 0) });
            li.Add(new WebClientEx() { ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("Source IP Address 3"), 0) });

            foreach (WebClientEx web in li)
            {
                string html = web.DownloadString("https://www.ugtop.com/spill.shtml");
                Debug.WriteLine("xxxxxxxxx"); //I want to know source ip actually used, so I want to get source ip address from web instance. 
            }
        }
    }

    public class WebClientEx : WebClient
    {
        public IPEndPoint ipEndPoint;
        public IPEndPoint BindIPEndPointCallback(ServicePoint servicePoint, IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint, int retryCount) => ipEndPoint;

        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.ConnectionGroupName = ipEndPoint.ToString();
            request.ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate = BindIPEndPointCallback;
            return request;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply access `web.ipEndPoint` in that `foreach()`?

Comment: web.ipEndPoint is the member variable I added.
Therefore, it is not Local IP actually used.